# Backbone subview containing view template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, chaplinjs

Our project uses Backbone and Chaplin, and it contains a bunch of components with models, views and sometimes multiple templates for each component depending of the case. We are refactoring the most basic ones into smaller components that provide event handling and a basic template, and for modals this would be a general dialog without any content inside it.

This basic version should be called into the modal view as a subview, and then one of the possible modal templates should be rendered inside the basic template. Currently all of the modal templates share this basic structure:

```
<div class="modal {{modal_class}}" id="{{id}}" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" tabindex="0">
      ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As every modal template shares the same basic structure, that is `.modal > .modal-container > .modal-content`, I want to split it up like this:

**modalContainer**

```
<div class="modal {{modal_class}}" id="{{id}}" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

**modalTemplates**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" tabindex="0">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The main idea is that the modal templates are inserted inside the modalContainer template, and the container must be a subview of the modal view. Which would be the best way to implement this taking into account performance?

Comment: I can understand why you want to inject content into `modal-body`, I don't see any good reason to split the generic model template into two. What do you achieve by this?

Comment: BTW missing a quote at `class="modal-container>`

Comment: @TJ It's not just a generic template, there are two templates and we want to create a common base for those and other templates that may come.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. You mean the skelton of a modal itself can vary? Instead of just the content?